# Foundation font sizing in lists

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation. I've got a dropdown menu structured like so:

`<div class="dropdown"><ul><li>...`

I want to change the font size of all the elements in this menu. However, when I try to target them with `.dropdown { font-size: 0.5em; }`, I get overridden by this rule from the Foundation styles: `ul, ol, dl { font-size: 1rem; }`.

Is my only recourse to target the list elements specifically? i.e. `.dropdown ul { font-size: 0.5em; }`. This introduces a lot of unwanted specificity. To make matters worse, there's a second font-size rule for nested lists, so I would have to account for that as well with even more specific selectors. Seems like I'll trip over this a lot.

Am I missing something? How do I make this not such an annoyance?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to either make your styles more specific *or* alter the default size for all lists.

The reason being `ul, ol, dl { font-size: 1rem }`.  If it had been using em or % instead, then it would have happily taken its context from the ancestor element (`.dropdown` in this case, which is .5em).

So, you could either do this:

```
ul, ol, dl {
    font-size: 1em; // or 100%
}
```

Or

```
.dropdown ul, .dropdown ol, .dropdown dl {
    font-size: 1em; // or 100%
}
```

They'll both do what you're looking for without the side effects that would come along with your proposed styles when there's nesting involved (`.dropdown ul { font-size: .5em }`).  The second option I've provided should be specific enough to override styles for nested lists.

Comment: Bummer, that's what I was afraid of. I guess it's just a pragmatic trade-off for the creators -- deciding that preventing nested lists from decreasing in size thanks to `em`s was worth this small downside.